# CircleCI: job for test using karma

Tags: circleci

I try to run unit-tests on CI in my project, but for some reason, I get the error Please set env variable CHROME_BIN.

So, I add `environment: - CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome`, but it still doesn't work. I also try setting the browser to ChromeHeadless in the karma.config file by using `config.set({browsers: ['ChromeHeadless']})`. Does anyone have an idea what might be the issue?

Here is code of my test job:

```
  test:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/node:16.19.0-browsers
        environment:
          - CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: npm install
      - run:
          command: npm test
```

Here is error from CI:

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
npm test

> api-data@0.0.0 test
> ng test

- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
07 01 2023 23:22:42.949:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
07 01 2023 23:22:42.959:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.4.1 server started at http://localhost:9876/
07 01 2023 23:22:42.959:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome with concurrency unlimited
07 01 2023 23:22:42.961:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
07 01 2023 23:22:43.020:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
    Can not find the binary /usr/bin/google-chrome
    Please set env variable CHROME_BIN
07 01 2023 23:22:43.020:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stdout: 
07 01 2023 23:22:43.020:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome stderr:
```

Comment: Your current `environment` is an array containing one string of `CHROME_BIN=/usr/bin/google-chrome`, rather than a map: `CHROME_BIN: /usr/bin/google-chrome`.

Comment: Still the same error when i change to ``CHROME_BIN: /usr/bin/google-chrome``

Comment: I resolved the problem, but I'm not happy with this (probably there is a better way to do it). On the steps, I just added: ``- browser-tools/install-chrome: channel: stable``
and add orb:
``orbs:
  browser-tools: circleci/browser-tools@1.4.0``